# Select first value then fill with null for unique id

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm using a Postgres database.

I've been trying to resolve this for hours and read dozens of topics with no result yet

Since I don't know how to explain my issue with words, here is what I need by example :

My query is

```sql
select distinct chiffre_affaires.contrat_pentete_id,
       chiffre_affaires.chiffre_affaires_id,
       chiffre_affaires.chiffre_affaires_montant_total
from chiffre_affaires;
```

Current output :

| contrat_pentete_id | chiffre_affaires_id | chiffre_affaires_montant_total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 111.7848 |
| 1 | 2 | 111.7848 |
| 1 | 3 | 111.7848 |
| 1 | 4 | 111.7848 |
| 1 | 5 | 111.7848 |
| 1 | 6 | 111.7848 |
| 2 | 7 | 90 |
| 2 | 8 | 90 |
| 2 | 9 | 90 |
| 2 | 10 | 90 |

Expected output :

> null values can be replaced by 0, both null or 0 would work

| contrat_pentete_id | chiffre_affaires_id | chiffre_affaires_montant_total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 111.7848 |
| 1 | 2 | null |
| 1 | 3 | null |
| 1 | 4 | null |
| 1 | 5 | null |
| 1 | 6 | null |
| 2 | 7 | 90 |
| 2 | 8 | null |
| 2 | 9 | null |
| 2 | 10 | null |

Thank you in advance for any help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Edouard H. I finally wrote a script that did the job.

Here is the solution :

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ca.contrat_pentete_id,
                ca.chiffre_affaires_id,
                ca.chiffre_affaires_annee_mois,
                CASE
                    WHEN ca.chiffre_affaires_id =
                         first_value(ca.chiffre_affaires_id) OVER (PARTITION BY ca.contrat_pentete_id ORDER BY ca.chiffre_affaires_annee_mois)
                        THEN ca.chiffre_affaires_montant_total
                    END AS montant_facture
FROM chiffre_affaires AS ca
ORDER BY ca.contrat_pentete_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Trying to understand what you want to achieve : for a group of rows with same *contrat_pentete_id*, ordered by *chiffre_affaires_id* ASC, you want to display the
*chiffre_affaires_montant_total* value for the first row, and NULL for the next rows. If so, you can try this :

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
       ca.contrat_pentete_id,
       ca.chiffre_affaires_id,
       CASE
         WHEN ca.chiffre_affaires_id = first_value (ca.chiffre_affaires_id) OVER (ORDER BY ca.chiffre_affaires_id)
         THEN ca.chiffre_affaires_montant_total
         ELSE NULL
       END AS ca.chiffre_affaires_montant_total
FROM chiffre_affaires AS ca
ORDER BY ca.contrat_pentete_id, ca.chiffre_affaires_id
```

Comment: Thank you very much, after some updates based on your script I got what I needed !

Comment: Thank you to accept the answer so that to close the question.